# Vuetify CRUD table updating UI on dialog cancel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm following the Vuetify "CRUD Actions" data table example found here [Vuetify CRUD Actions Data Table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions) and have an issue where the UI is being updated for some fields upon editing a row and cancelling the edit dialogue. When I edit an item in the dialogue, two of the four fields I am showing in the table are editing real-time as I edit their value in the dialogue. The other two fields are not. They are working properly. The difference between the fields that work and do not work is one is a property on the main object and the other is a property within an object on the main object (see code below). The properties in bold are the ones that are editing real-time in the table as I change their values in the edit dialogue.

```
  editedItem: {
    hostName: "",
    serialNumber: "",
    mode: {
      **name: "",**
    },
    location: {
      **name: "",**
    },
  },
```

Below are two images, before and after editing that show the issue. As you can see, the "Location" field updates real-time in the table as I am editing, and the "Name" field does not. I'm thinking this has to do with the binding, but not sure how to fix it.

[Before editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSEnh.png)

[After editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyzXZ.png)

The only difference from what is shown in the example is I am using axios to retrieve the data and computed properties for the table data as shown below.

```
computed: {
  headers() {
    return [
      { text: "Reader Name", value: "hostName" },
      { text: "Reader Serial Number", value: "serialNumber" },
      { text: "Reader Location", value: "location.name" },
      { text: "Reader Mode", value: "mode.name" },
      { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false },
    ];
  },
  formTitle() {
    return this.editedIndex === -1 ? "New Item" : "Edit Item";
  },
},
```